# Using not common unicode character in Sphinx

Tags: python, unicode, python-sphinx

I need to write **Lévy** in sphinx documentation. The documentation is created from docstring in Python script.

In Python docstring I can write **L\xc3\xa9vy** and it throw now error when I run the script.

But the spinx render it as **LÃ©vy**.

How can I achieve that text **Lévy** will not cause the crash of Python script (both P2.7 and P3.x) and also will be rendered by sphinx correctly?

(I will not need this often because the documentation is in English, so any workaround is acceptable.)

Comment: Write `u'L\xe9vy'` in a unicode docstring.

Comment: @lenz Thanks for response. But it does not work.

Comment: What exactly happens? Is there a crash? Error message? How can we reproduce it?

Comment: @lenz Sorry it works. Originally I tried to break docstring with """+u'...'+""" and it does not work. But now I change the whole docstring into unicode u"""...""" and it works! Please create an answer, so I can accept it.